# Github <> remote server, auto deploy, the webhook doesn't work

Tags: php, github, git-pull, webhooks

When I push to the github project from any local computer, I want my remote server to pull automatically (its a php website project)

I've searched on google and youtube but having spent an entire day I didn't find how do that.

In my `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/website/`, there are the `.git` folder and the `github.php` file deploy

`github.php` :

```
<?php
`git pull origin master`;
`touch test.txt`;
```

If I execute `./github.php` from a terminal, the "script" works well. The pull works too.

If I enter the url `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/website/github.php`, from my browser, the pull doesn't work, but a `test.txt` is created.

If I push a commit from any local computer, the remote server doesn't pull automaticaly and the `test.txt` file isn't created;

In my remote server, the permissions are :

- for .git directory : drwxrwxrwx  8 toji     toji      4096 Jun 14 13:31 (-R)
- for github.php : -rwxrwxrwx  1 toji     toji        51 Jun 14 13:28

In my github account, I add a webhook service : 
Payload URL is : `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/website/github.php`

Please help me determine the origin of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your PHP is valid since you need to use something like exec() to use git in php... I had the same problem a few days ago and found little tools to help deploy your code from Github or Gitlab so I created Deepl.io to handle Web-Hooks and call scripts to deploy on your own server.
This handles the JSON that's sent from github or gitlab and can be used for multiple repositories and branches etc. You can use your own PHP or shell scripts after receiving the pull notification and it sends you status e-mails after every deploy...
Check it out: http://deepl.io

The shell scrip that is actually executed (called by php) is something as follows;

```
#!/bin/sh

TRAGET="/path/to/target/folder"
LOG="/path/to/your/log/file.log"
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")

# Start Sctipt
echo "
SCRIPT START: $NOW" >> $LOG

cd $TRAGET >> $LOG

# checkout correct branch
git checkout master >> $LOG

# clear untracked files
git clean -df >> $LOG

# revert local changes
git checkout -- . >> $LOG

# pulling new stuff
git pull >> $LOG

echo "SCRIPT END.
" >> $LOG
```